# How to set the AppointmentItem BodyFormat from OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML to OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

The MailItem has BodyFormat property to change the body format, but the AppointmentItem does not have this property. How can I set the appointment's body format for outlook 2016 and office 365.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the plain text `AppointmentItem.Body` property.

Comment: but appointment.body always keeps extra space at the end of string.when i compare the appointmnet.body with the written text,it gives me false as result.

Comment: Never compare plain text body of two items - it is not natively stores but rather converted from RTF or HTML. The conversion depends on the store kind and Outlook version.